# Uncaught ReferenceError: __HMR_CONFIG_NAME__ is not defined at overlay.ts:7:23

Tags: reactjs, vite

- I'm using vite(v5.1.3) with [backend integration](https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html)
- auto refresh, and build are working well.
- but I get the error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: __HMR_CONFIG_NAME__ is not defined` on dev mode.

[image]

How to deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that ensuring that Vite shuts down properly when closing the application allows it to inject those dependencies properly when booting up again. If you perform any dependency updates while your project is not running but Vite is, that could cause this error.